# How to Read This Json Quiz File in jQuery mobile webapp?

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

```
[{"TestNum":1,"TestItem":"What is JS","TestA":"JAVA SCRIPT","TestB":"JAVA SAMPLE","TestC":"JAVA SERVER","TestD":"JAVA SAFE","TestAnswer":"A"},
{"TestNum":2,"TestItem":"Where is USA","TestA":"NEXT TO CANADA","TestB":"NEXT TO AFRICA","TestC":"NEXT TO CHINA","TestD":"NEXT TO AMERICA","TestAnswer":"A"},
{"TestNum":3,"TestItem":"Which is a mobile os","TestA":"UBUNTU","TestB":"OSX","TestC":"WINDOWS","TestD":"WP","TestAnswer":"D"}]
```

This is a quiz json file, and I tried to use ajax in jQuery mobile to make it displayed next question like a Quiz by pushing the NEXTBOTTON, but the result just confused me that it will display all the Test Answers. I am new to jQuery, and in C# I can use `List<T>[int]` to display each character. Anybody please help me out with this question. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Use **[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** to read the JSON string into a JSON Object.

Once you have the object it will be an array of question objects, so, for example, to get the first question's TestItem property you would write:

```
var questions = JSON.parse(data);
var testitem1 = questions[0].TestItem;
```

Where data is your JSON string returned by the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing it in a wrong way by casting a wrong example.   I'll try this later ..